# Помогите с созданием алгоритма решения задачи: Количество пар

Tags: python

Помните, что студент Арман подарил волшебную шляпу преподавателям? Теперь он стал самым любимым студентом в группе! Но если вы думаете, что любимчикам задают только самые простые задачи, то это не всегда правда. Преподаватель по С++ отправил Арману отдельное домашнее задание, которое Арман, к сожалению, не смог выполнить. Помогите Арману не выпасть из списка любимчиков преподавателя, решите задачу. Задание следующее. Cколько существует таких пар `(i,  j)`, что `1 <= i  <= j  <= n, j - i <= a`

**Input Format**

В первой строке записаны два целых положительных числа `n` и `a`.

**Constraints**

```
1 <= n <= 1000000, 0 <= a <= 1000000
```

**Output Format**

Выведите одно целое число - количество пар

**Sample Input 0**

```
3 1
```

**Sample Output 0**

```
5
```

**Sample Input 1**

```
5 4
```

**Sample Output 1**

```
15
```

**Sample Input 2**

```
10 5
```

**Sample Output 2**

```
45
```

**РЕШЕНИЕ НУЖНО НА PYTHON**

есть код, который я написал, но он проходит только 1 проверку:

```
n, a = map(int, input().split())

g1 = 0
g2 = 0

for i, j in zip(range(1, n + 1), range(1, n + 1)):
    if 1 <= i <= j <= n:
            g1 += 1
for j in range(0, a + 1):
    for i in range(1, j + 1):
        if j - i <= a:
            g2 += 1

print(g1 + g2)
```

Comment: я отредактировал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

первый цикл `for` не нужен. надо генерировать значения от `1` до `n + 1`, а не до `a + 1`

```
n, a = map(int, input().split())

g2 = 0

for j in range(0, n + 1):
    for i in range(1, j + 1):
        if j - i <= a:
            g2 += 1

print(g2)
```

либо так, без создания дополнительных переменных

```
print(sum(1
          for j in range(1, n + 1)
          for i in range(1, j + 1)
          if j - i <= a))
```

вычисление всех значения не обязательна

```
print(sum(min(j, a + 1) for j in range(1, n + 1)))
```

Comment: 3 проверки проходит, а остальные по времени не идут

Comment: 4 проверки прошло, дальше уж сервер дольше 10 секунд не принимает

Comment: видимо надо было учить c++

Comment: спасибо большое, за ответ

Comment: а строчка кода, где без вычисления всех значений дало максимальный результат

Comment: еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 2):

А зачем тут вообще циклы?

`(2n - a)(a + 1)/2` — ответ

Comment: ваш код выполнился лучше, но всё равно 1 проверку не прошёл

Comment: так же спасибо вам большое

Comment: Ну ту нет проверок на разумность входных данных. В частности, предполагается что a<n